# Why does the author write "listen" for a thing he is doing?

Tags: present-continuous, sequence-of-tenses

> I'm sitting here with a warm nostalgic feeling **as I listen to** the final master recordings Peter has sent over

Why is it not "am listening" is it because sit is already present continuous so there is no need to repeat it?  I only see these reason to justify  it

Answer (score 5):

The word *as* in the phrase *as I listen* already sets a framework that is ongoing in present time. There is no need to reinforce that with present continuous.

Comment: I don't think it's that simple. For example "A nostalgic feeling comes over me as I am listening to the recordings." is perfectly good.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of the answer, but I think it might be that the simple form suggests that the two actions substantially overlap in duration, but the continuous from is more appropriate to suggest that it completely contains the other action in time.

When you say: "I'm sitting here with a warm nostalgic feeling as I listen to the final master recordings," it suggests that the feeling and the listening have a similar duration in time.

If you say: "A nostalgic feeling comes over me as I am listening to the recordings" (as suggested in one of the comments), it suggests that the feeling does not last as long as the listening.

Specifically, the former suggests that the listening immediately led to the feeling and that the feeling will persist as long as you listen (even if that is not actually the case).  The latter expression suggests that the feeling came upon you suddenly after the listening had already begun.  Your action of listening is interrupted by a feeling.

Comment: It's better if your answers *are* sure. Anything less than sure isn't an answer, but could be a valuable comment.

Comment: Could it mean that the listening will be completed or that he listens to it very often

Comment: Normally, the simple present often has a habitual reading; however, combined with the continuous present in the first clause, the meaning here strongly suggests a single session of listening.  The first sentence is clearly the most idiomatic English, and using  " "am listening" sounds overly precise without much difference in meaning in this case.  It has something to do with using "as"  or "while," because you could also idiomatically say: "I am here siting with a warm feeling and listening to the recordings.